# Apache config If statement with OS environment variable

Tags: apache, apache2.4

How can I conditionally set a proxy based on an OS level environment variable (`printenv` would contain something like ENV=qa, ENV=prod, etc)? Something like this:

```
<If "${ENV} == 'qa'">
  ProxyPass "/" "www.google-qa.com"
</If>
<If "${ENV} == 'prod'">
  ProxyPass "/" "www.google-production.com"
</If>
```

With something like the above I am getting: `Cannot parse condition clause: Parse error near '$'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two alternate syntaxes work instead:

`<If "'${ENV}' == 'qa'">`

or

`<If "reqenv('ENV') == 'qa'">`

But ProxyPass cannot be encapsulated in `<If>`, largely because this a per-request check and happens later in processing then when ProxyPass has to execute.

It is probably more straightforward to do your proxying via mod_rewrite and check %{ENV:ENV} in a `RewriteCond`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENV} =qa
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.google-qa.com/$1 [P]
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENV} =prod
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.google-production.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: thanks! the example above isn't exactly what I have, what would be the rewrite equivalent of what I have actually have? `ProxyPass "/api/" "balancer://appcluster/api/"`, `ProxyPassReverse "/api/" "balancer:/appcluster/api/"`, and `BalancerMember "https://example.net:443"`. I don't need the balancer stuff

Comment: I missed [P] before completely and now just edited. I think you'd need to define both balancers than just plug in the balancer:// URL in lieu of the direct URL with the P flag